# How to deal with Pandas dataframe column with list containing string values, get unique words

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do some basic operations on a dataframe column (called `dimensions`) that contains a list. Do basic operations like `df['dimensions'].str.replace()` work when the dataframe column contains a list? It did not work for me. I also tried to replace the text in the column using `re.sub()` method and it did not work either.

This is the last column in my dataframe:

```
**dimensions**

[50' long]    
None    
[70ft long, 19ft wide, 8ft thick]    
[5' high, 30' long, 18' wide]
```

**This is what I have tried, but it did not work:**

```
def dimension_unique_words(dimensions):
if dimensions != 'None':
    for value in dimensions:
        new_value = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]|ft|feet', ' ', value)
        new_value = ''.join([i for i in new_value if not i.isdigit()])
        return new_value

df['new_col'] = df['dimensions'].apply(dimension_unique_words)
```

**this is the output I got from my code:**

```
**new_col**

NaN    
None    
NaN    
None    
NaN    
None
```

What I want to do is to replace the numbers and the units [ft, feet, ']  in the column called `dimensions` with a space and then apply the `df.unique()` on that column to get the unique values which are [long, wide, thick, high].

*The expected output would be:*

```
**new_col**

[long]    
None   
[long, wide, thick]    
[high, long, wide]
```

**...then I want to apply the `df.unique()` on the `new_col` to get [long, wide, thick, high]**

How to do that?

Comment: What is your expected output from the given data above?

Comment: I expect to get a list that contains [long, wide, thick, high].  after deleting the numbers and the units and then use the unique() method

Comment: But you have three long values?  What would be your exact output from these data?

Comment: I am looking only for the unique values without repetition. you are right, long is repeated three times, I just need one of them. @scott Boston I edited my question with the required output. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Seems each element in 'dimenstions' is either None or else a list that only has one element. You could simply assign `df['dimensions'] = df['dimensions'].apply(lambda col: col[0] if col else None, axis=1)` but we need to tweak that lambda for the Nones. You could also do df['dimensions'].explode()` but that could cause multiple rows if the list has multiple elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we deal with the annoyance that your 'dimensions' column is sometimes None, sometimes a list of one string element. So extract that element when it's non-null:

```
df['dimensions2'] = df['dimensions'].apply(lambda col: col[0] if col else None)
```

Next, get all alphabetic strings in each row, excluding measurements:

```
>>> df['dimensions2'].str.findall(r'\b([a-zA-Z]+)')
0                 [long]
1                   None
2    [long, wide, thick]
3     [high, long, wide]
```

Note we use `\b` word-boundary (to exclude the 'ft' from '30ft'), and to avoid misinterpreting `\b` as backslash we have to use r'' rawstring on the regex.

This gives you a list. You wanted a set, to prevent duplicates occurring, so:

```
 df['dimensions2'].str.findall(r'\b([a-zA-Z]+)').apply(lambda l: set(l) if l else None)
0                 {long}
1                   None
2    {thick, long, wide}
3     {high, long, wide}
```

Comment: I used the three lines of codes you generated but It did not work. I do not know if I miss something or not. the first line extracts only the first element of the col. and even it did not remove the measurements and the units. thank you for helping out.

Comment: @Eng_GR: they do work. If you want to store the output of these commands, assign them: `df['dimensions'] = df['dimensions2'].str.findall(r'\b([a-z]+)').apply(lambda l: set(l) if l else None)`

Comment: when I run it, i found the output for the first row is {long} which is right, the second row is None, which is right. However, the output from the third row is {long} which is not right. it is supposed to be {long, Wide, Thick}. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks a lot @smci

Comment: Eng_GR: because you specifically showed they were all lowercase. But if your dimensions can be uppercase, then you want `r'\b([a-zA-Z]+)'` in the regex. Your question should show what your data looks like. Mixed-case, and repetition of the dimension words within a single row.

Answer (score 0):

1. use `str.findall` to find all dimensions values to a list.
2. use `explode` to explode the list to elements with the same index.
3. then use `groupby(level=0).unique()` to drop duplicates by index to a list.

```
df['new_col'] = (
  df['dimensions'].fillna('').astype(str)
 .str.findall(r'\b[a-zA-Z]+\b')
 .explode().dropna()
 .groupby(level=0).unique()
)
```

use `df['new_col'].explode().dropna().unique()` to get the unique dimensions values.

```
array(['long', 'wide', 'thick', 'high'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: thanks @Ferris, your solution assumes that I know the unique list in advance ['long', 'wide', 'thick', 'high'], but I do not know that list in advance.

Comment: Ok, if the dimensions are unknown, then use `.str.findall(r'\b[a-zA-Z]+\b')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

First we deal with the annoyance that your 'dimensions' column is sometimes None, sometimes a list of one string element. So extract that element when it's non-null:

```
df['dimensions2'] = df['dimensions'].apply(lambda col: col[0] if col else None)
```

Next, get all alphabetic strings in each row, excluding measurements:

```
>>> df['dimensions2'].str.findall(r'\b([a-z]+)')
0                 [long]
1                   None
2    [long, wide, thick]
3     [high, long, wide]
```

Note we use `\b` word-boundary (to exclude the 'ft' from '30ft'), and to avoid misinterpreting `\b` as backslash we have to use r'' rawstring on the regex.